# How to select an element which parent is not specified class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to hide an element if its parent does not have a certain class:

#### HTML

```
<li class="current_page_parent">
    <a href="parent.html">Parent</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

#### jQuery

```
jQuery("ul.children").hide();
```

Currently always hides `<ul class="children">` regardless of class. I would like to close it only if parent is `:not` an `<li class="current_page_parent">`.

#### I've tried:

```
jQuery("ul.children:not(:parent.current_page_ancestor)").hide();
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery("li:not(.current_page_parent) ul.children").hide();
```

Comment: +1 this will be microscopically faster on modern browsers than my deleted answer (which used `:not(.current_page_ancestor > ul)`), because it's a valid CSS selector, unlike mine. CSS3 `:not()` only accepts one simple selector - selector sequences will be handled by jQuery's selector engine instead, which is slower than `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: smart. thank you. @BoltClock yours also worked but this one does look more understandable.

Comment: @BoltClock:Thx for explaining why it would be faster.

Comment: No problem. I don't usually care about performance, but I thought this was worth explaining.

Comment: This solution will not work if we have a 2nd <li> element in the parents that does not have the class "current_page_parent". The solution given by @2nd is much robuster.

Comment: @BoltClock can you provide your deleted solution please? I am interested in a case where I should start selection from child but not having a specific parent.

Answer (score 61):

The best way I think:

```
$(".children").not(".current_page_parent .children").hide();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1337/EmAPQ/)

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer, because it covers a more general approach.

Comment: **Warning!** Not a good answer. The above approach would select all the children (N nodes, while N → ∞ in theory) and only then would filter the children result set. While `$(":not(.parent) .children")` would filter the children on-the-fly creating immediately a small result set.

Comment: @AlexMelw you misunderstood question. There is many elements to be hidden and only one visible.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('ul').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent('.current_page_parent').length === 0
}).hide();
```

Comment: in my scope necessary to use a if on the length

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to *first* filter out the `ul` elements with a "bad" parent and *then* select all the children:

```
jQuery("ul:not(:parent.current_page_ancestor).children")
```