# Uisng jQuery to target all dl tags who do not have a specific parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a jQuery function that select and receives the text from a website that is designed like this:

```
<dl>
    <dd> hey </dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dd> how's it goin</dd>
</dl>
<div style="border:1px solid grey; background:#eee; padding:1em;">
    <dl> 
        <dd>don't select this</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

When I use this code:

```
$("dd").each(function(){
    transcript += $(this).text();
})
```

I select the text within all 3 of the dl tags, however, I only want to select the text within the first 2 dl tags. Is there any way to filter out the text I get by somehow saying that I don't want the text from dl tags that have a parent div with the specific style said in the code I posted? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is this HTML wrapped in? Couldn't you do something like `$('div > dl > dd')`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784741/how-to-select-an-element-which-parent-is-not-specified-class

Comment: do you have the ability to edit the HTML?

Comment: what is parent of what is shown? Easy if you start there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("dd").not("div dl dd");
```

Comment: Thats great! Didn't know that is possible.

Comment: This worked! Because the other dl tags were in a div as well, I had to be a little more specific by saying div[style='border:1px solid grey; background:#eee; padding:1em;'], but after doing that I got it to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you were to give the `<dd>`s that you don't want a CSS class, you can then easily use the `:not()` selector to do this:

HTML:

```
<dd class="noselect">
```

Script:

```
$("dd:not(.noselect)").each(function() {
```

It will select all `<dd>` elements which don't have the `noselect` class.

See https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ for an overview of `:not()`

Answer (score 0):

If those are in `<body>` you can simply do

```
$('body > dl dd');
```

Do similar depending on whatever parent they all reside in

Answer (score -2):

```
$("dd").eq(0).text()
```

will give you first dd text

and

```
$("dd").eq(1).text()
```

will give you second dd text