# Select all DOM elements not under a specific parent with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is a simple example of my html stucture

```
<div>
    <p class="doNotWant">
        HTML stucture is not set in stone
        <a class="linkToSelect">do not want</a> 
    </p>
</div>
<p>
   html structure and tags may vary, very simplified example
   <a class="linkToSelect">want this one</a> 
</p>
```

then I'm trying to select only the link ***not under*** the "doNotWant" parent class in my javascript...

```
$(document).on('click', '.linkToSelect', function (e) { 
    // this code selects both links
    console.log('my logic'); 
}
```

I've tried using [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) but not had any success yet.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784741/how-to-select-an-element-which-parent-is-not-specified-class

Comment: Since I need practice with recursion, I did this, see if it helps you. https://jsfiddle.net/qx3n4r57/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jquery you can use the `:not()` selector.

You can do the following if you don't know the parent element but know that its parent is a `div`.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div > :not(.doNotWant) > .linkToSelect', function (e) {
  console.log('your logic');
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th769dr1/7/)

Comment: your fiddle works but your selector is too specific, i need it off the div (or other parent), cant use the p tag so close to the link... `$(document).on('click', 'div :not(.doNotWant)  .linkToSelect', function (e) {` doesn't work for me though, which is slight change to what you've provided.

Comment: @Ninjanoel I edited my answer and the fiddle to fit your requirements

Comment: I've come to the conclusion what I need will have to be solved some other way. Your '>' means direct child. I really need to practice writing html to get the answer I want, my document is really complicated, there are no direct children options.

Comment: In this case you can reduce the selector to `div :not(.doNotWant) > .linkToSelect` if you're unsure of the direct parent of `.doNotWant`. I believe that you have to precise the position of the element that you want to select with `:not()` using it's parent, itself or its child. I have to do further researches to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

Using `:not()` change your selector to:

```
$(document).on('click', 'p:not(".doNotWant") .linkToSelect', function(e) {
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'p:not(".doNotWant") .linkToSelect', function(e) {
  // this code selects both links
  console.log('my logic');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="doNotWant">
    HTML stucture is not set in stone
    <a class="linkToSelect">do not want</a>
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  html structure and tags may vary, very simplified example
  <a class="linkToSelect">want this one</a>
</p>
```